# VM refuses key on Windows

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, putty, vagrant

My Vagrant VM is up and running, but if i check netstat, it is just `ESTABLISHED` but not `LISTENING`.

```
  TCP    192.168.56.1:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.56.1:50973     192.168.56.101:22      ESTABLISHED
```

Thouz as i found out, this apparently is not an issue, I can not connect to it using putty because it refuses my key.

```
login as: vagrant
Server refused our key
vagrant@192.168.56.101's password:
```

I am using a private key without passphrase that is stored locally and known to putty. 
I configured vagrant to use it in the config.yaml

```
ssh:
    host: null
    port: null
    private_key_path: ./puphpet/files/dot/ssh/vagrant_key
```

In the `vagrant_key` Folder i have the public key as `vagrant` and `vagrant.pub` and the private key as `vagrant.ppk`

Anyone any Ideas or Hints?

---

**EDIT:** i adjusted my Public SSH File (`vagrant.pub`) from Puttygen which now looks like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAsD+KWzLA96mAM9hkwy/xWdRT6+aUJ72M2ZyrZMk/GZTGfZxPXKgNvhPB/2AF3tVikcp8XNw5iVN/Lfu6+9JCzeDl3E4r9Xcbx0zCeclOY8ofLCD1rsKRCC/E33aew/y4QMkGfZQeXj3mVsuQxuPrr5tCTziKUKz7QTNn/MLINa1YuqsO5aqO1ujCeT2RjwShXVcvjFzT9/fRXiaH0M1hygcuIYY3T8MOp6dGPoBHB6WOuVgv5X+BTsilRuL+mQTWnZZw93NF2ySgEZFHwPoMLBCCc+A1quZV+aoDBTaVsOdsSGeCWMAW5oytsG7M/ATUDmZOI7D+M9UWIXkdvImusQ== rsa-key-20140423
```

It still doesn't work.

---

**EDIT:** While i couldn't fix my Putty Problem (*yet*), thanks to [@user1301428](https://superuser.com/users/179116/user1301428) i found a way to connect to my VM using vagrant ssh, which can be used under windows if you have the ssh.exe from git in your PATH Variable. Read [this Stackoverflow article here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482763/532495) for help.

Comment: It's not that you can't connect to it via SSH because the connection is established, that simply means that the connection has been successful. The problem is another one. 1) How did you generate the key pair? 2) Can you post the contents of `/var/log/auth.log`? 3) I am not extremely familiar with Vagrant, but in `config.yaml`, shouldn't `private_key_path` be something like `./puphpet/files/dot/ssh/vagrant_key/vagrant.ppk`, i.e. including the name of the key?

Comment: @user1301428 
1) I generated teh key pair using puttygen.
2) Where do i find the auth.log on my Windows machine?
3) the `private_key_path` actually has to be set like this.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the public key? I think I know what the problem is but I just want to make sure.

Comment: @user1301428 I did. You think that might be the problem?

Comment: Yep, see my answer below :)

Comment: I had the same issue, I finally gave up and tried to enter `vagrant` as password and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this public key instead:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAsD+KWzLA96mAM9hkwy/xWdRT6+aUJ72M2ZyrZMk/GZTGfZxPXKgNvhPB/2AF3tVikcp8XNw5iVN/Lfu6+9JCzeDl3E4r9Xcbx0zCeclOY8ofLCD1rsKRCC/E33aew/y4QMkGfZQeXj3mVsuQxuPrr5tCTziKUKz7QTNn/MLINa1YuqsO5aqO1ujCeT2RjwShXVcvjFzT9/fRXiaH0M1hygcuIYY3T8MOp6dGPoBHB6WOuVgv5X+BTsilRuL+mQTWnZZw93NF2ySgEZFHwPoMLBCCc+A1quZV+aoDBTaVsOdsSGeCWMAW5oytsG7M/ATUDmZOI7D+M9UWIXkdvImusQ==
```

and add this to the `authorized_keys` file.

There is an issue with the format of Putty-generated keys when used with SSH, it might easily be the cause of that error message you are seeing.

**Update**
With regards to how to configure all this on Windows, have a look at [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885108/ssh-to-vagrant-box-in-windows), maybe it will point you in the right direction.

**Update 2**
Try saving the public key as `insecure_public_key.ppk` (see [this article](http://jinsunspace.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/vagrant-on-window.html))

Comment: How do i add it to the authorized_keys file on windows?

Comment: @AndreschSerj Again, I am not very familiar with vagrant, but can you try `vagrant ssh` and update the file now through this? After you have solved the ssh issues you can start using Putty.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but that did not solve the issue, nor can i use `vagrant ssh` since windows has no ssh command line tool :-( I agree on your public key solution thou so +1 :D

Comment: I know that Article. Didn't help :(

Comment: @AndreschSerj have you also checked the section about patching ssh code? That should enable you to use `vagrant ssh` on Windows. Also, answer updated.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Also, after updating the public key, try deleting and recreating the VM, it might also be some weird-i-don't-know-what-kind-of-caching-problem.

Comment: Adding the path to git's ssh.exe worked! Now i can access my machine via vagrant ssh! How did i overread that? Thanks a lot thou! Sadly it doesn't solve the putty problem but it solves my problem.

Comment: @AndreschSerj great that it worked! At least now you can try solving the Putty problem because you have access to the machine and you can update the `authorized_keys` file :)

Answer (score 2):

For security purposes I've set PuPHPet to disable the built-in SSH key and generate a unique key for each VM you up.

However, I should probably add a putty-compatible version, too!